# Python glob -- get newest file from list

Tags: python, list, file, path, glob

I am able to retrieve the list of files with similar names. What I am trying to do is retrieve the newest file in order to be manipulated. With glob, I am able to retrieve all of the files, but not the specific one.

Here is my sample code:

```
permissionCurrentDate = '\n'.join(glob.iglob(os.path.join("PermissionsOnSystems*")))
```

Here is the result when I print it:

```
PermissionsOnSystems2.txt

PermissionsOnSystems20170313-144036.txt
```

What I want is just `PermissionsOnSystems20170313-144036.txt`.

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on if you want the newest file from the perspective of access time, metadata change time, or modify time you can use `os.path.getatime`, `os.path.getctime` or `os.path.getmtime`.  So something like:

```
max(glob.iglob('PermissionsOnSystems*'), key=os.path.getmtime)
```

Comment: Since this requires calling stat() on many files in a directory, scandir might be more efficient.